# How to implement this view in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I want to know how I can implement this component in a rounded way by opening the section of the bottom bar

https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-42c1c073d593.gif
https://i.ibb.co/QjMwHwq/descarga.png
If you can tell me the name of this, or any help, I appreciate it

Comment: You can do it using `View` (with flexbox), `Animated`, `TouchableOpacity`, `ImageBackground`, ... APIs from **React Native** & navigate using **React Navigation**. Here are some links for your help [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox], [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html]

Comment: You shouldn't ask question on how to make something, but discuss the issues you are having during your work. Along with what you've tried so far to achieve the expected result

Comment: You can find really helpful tutorials regarding React native layouts, React navigation & multiple other packages for UI & other functionalities

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `View` component (with flexbox) with these style properties: `borderTopLeftRadius` and `borderTopRightRadius`. This will round the corners of your `View` which is by default a rectangle